# Leaflet - Calculate view bounds in Km

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the distance in KM of the current view in Leaflet.
For now I'm retrieving data from the API using the getBounds() of the current view, which gives me the SW&NE coords. Is there a way to know the widht & height in KM of the current view?
Image example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

The purpose of this is to use Redis to get coordinates using BYBOX feature, but it only accepts distances.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calc the distance between the latlngs of the bounds:

```js
function getWidthHeightInKM(){
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    var width = map.distance(bounds.getNorthWest(), bounds.getNorthEast()) / 1000;
    var height = map.distance(bounds.getNorthWest(), bounds.getSouthWest()) / 1000;

    return {
        width,
        height
    }
}
console.log(getWidthHeightInKM())
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/8cjjQiA9rWWeBWH3